# Multiple radio button values using PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

I am new to PHP and I will google several websites but could not find any solution which I understand, so my question is quite complicated because I think I have the stupid question the answer will be highly appreciated

I have HTML code

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Sr.</td>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>Father Name</td>
                <td>Roll No.</td>
                <td>Gender</td>
                <td>Attendance</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>    
        <tbody>
            <?php $q=mysqli_query($dbc,"SELECT * FROM students");
                while ($r=mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)):
        ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?=$r['students_id']?></td>
                <td><?=$r['students_name']?></td>
                <td><?=$r['fname']?></td>
                <td><?=$r['students_reg']?></td>
                <td><?=$r['gender']?></td>
                <td>
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label>
                        <input type="radio" name="attendance[++i]" value="Present">
                                Present     
                        </label>
                        <label for="">
                        <input type="radio" name="attendance[++j]" value=Absent>
                                Absent
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <?php endwhile ?>
    </table>    
    <button class="btn btn-success form-control"  name="add_attendance">Register</button>
```

All values are fetched from a database which is inserted from another page except the last  which show the radio button my problem is I will not be able to select  more than one radio button means Present in one column and absent in other I want to select one button for each field which is fetch from database and when i submit form it store the radio button values parallel to that of record which is fetched?? i hope you understand my problem :(

Comment: So what exactly isn't working? I can see where on one you are using `attendance[++i]` and the other is a different counter - `attendance[++j]`

Comment: Why not use the `$r['students_id']` as the array name, and then it would be simpler to get the values on post -> `name="attendance[<?=$r['students_id']?>]"`

Comment: my problem is half solved now please please tell me how to store these radio button into database which is created dynamically ,

Comment: now i will be able select multiple radio button on each line but now how i inserted in sql db using one single click parallel to these id